# In isosceles $\triangle ABC$, $X$ is any point on $BC$. $P$ and $Q$ are the circumcentres of $\triangle ABX$ and $ACX$. Prove $APXQ$ is parallelogram.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

> $X$ is any point on the base of an isosceles triangle $ABC$. $P$ and $Q$ are the circumcentres of the $\triangle ABX$ and $\triangle ACX$. Prove that $APXQ$ is a parallelogram.

**My take on the question:**
It is easy to prove that the figure $APXQ$ is a kite, from the fact that the diagonals are perpendicular to each other.
To prove that the figure is a parallelogram, we need to prove that the radii of both the circle are equal. If we are able to prove that points $P$ and $Q$ are equidistant from $AX$, then by congruence the radii can be proved equal.
I am not able to proceed any further. Can someone help me figure out the next step?

Comment: @HenningMakholm my bad...I meant perpendicular...making the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base of the triangle is $BC$ right? And $X \in BC$? Since triangle $ABC$ is isosceles  $$\angle \, ACX = \angle \, ACB = \angle \,  ABC = \angle \, ABX = \beta$$

$$\angle \, AQX = 2 \, \angle \, ACX = 2 \beta$$ 
$$\angle \, APX = 2 \, \angle \, ABX = 2 \beta$$
Hence the two isosceles triangles $APX$ and $AQX$ are congruent which means $AP = AQ = XP = XQ$. The quad $APXQ$ is a rhombus.

Comment: Nice approach! I couldn't think of a way to use the information AB=AC...

Answer (score 1):

The perpendicular bisector of AX passess through P and Q.

Draw the perpendicular bisectors of BX and XC, passing through P and Q respectively, and intersect them with a line through A that is parallel to BC, forming a rectangle. Convince yourself that turning this rectangle through 180° interchanges both A and X, and P and Q.

[image: diagram goes here]

Here we have $BD=DX$ and $XE=EC$. Then

$$AF=DM=\tfrac12BX-MX = \tfrac12BM+\tfrac12MX-MX = \tfrac12MC-\tfrac12MX = \tfrac12XC = XE $$
So $AF=XE$ and rotating the rectangle by 180° interchanges A and X.

Comment: wait...won't that convincing require us to know that APXQ is a ||gm? How else can we convince ourselves?

Comment: @OsheenSachdev: No, that requires only some algebra on horizontal distances.

Comment: I like this approach and want to try this...can you elaborate on this a bit?

Comment: I basically don't know what you mean by "some algebra on horizontal distances"

Comment: @OsheenSachdev: See edit.